# TDD implementation of a set data structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, set, tdd

I am trying to implement a set data structure in Ruby using rspec. I have one test which does not seem to pass in the below code:

```
def add(element)
    if @set_data.include?(element)
        print "This element is already in the set!"
    else
        @set_data += [element]
    end
end
```

and this is the test for it:

```
it 'does not add an element if the element is already in the set' do
    set = SetDataStructure.new([1,2,3,4,5])
    set.add(4)
    expect(set).to eq("This element is already in the set!")
end
```

Output from running the test:

......This element is already in the set!F.

Failures:

1) SetDataStructure does not add an element if the element is already in the set
     Failure/Error: expect(set.to_a).to eq("This element is already in the set!")

```
   expected: "This element is already in the set!"
        got: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/set_data_structure_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.00348 seconds
8 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/set_data_structure_spec.rb:36 # SetDataStructure does not add an element if the element is already in the set

I also have the code published on my [GitHub](https://github.com/pinglinh/set_data_structure/tree/development).

I'd be ever so grateful if someone could enlighten me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to return the string from the `add` method in case the element is already present, you can modify your method and tests as below:

Method:

```
def add(element)
  if @set_data.include?(element)
    "This element is already in the set!"     # This will not print the statement, but return it
  else
    @set_data += [element]
  end
end
```

Test:

```
it 'does not add an element if the element is already in the set' do
  set = SetDataStructure.new([1,2,3,4,5])
  expect(set.add(4)).to eq("This element is already in the set!")
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is incorrect.

```
expect(set).to eq("This element is already in the set!")
```

Your set remains the same, you do not expect it to change to string.
This should be

```
it 'does not add an element if the element is already in the set' do
  set = SetDataStructure.new([1,2,3,4,5])
  expect { set.add(4) }.to output(/This element is already in the set!/).to_stdout
  # test that set has stayed the  same
  # you probably need to define (override) eq method for SetDataStructure
  expect(set).to eq(SetDataStructure.new([1,2,3,4,5]))
  # alternative is this
  expect(set.set_data).to eq([1,2,3,4,5])
end
```

Ruby's set wouldn't print any errors, it would just silently not add element to set. If you want that behavior, then expect set to stay the same when you add element

```
it 'does not add an element if the element is already in the set' do
  set = SetDataStructure.new([1,2,3,4,5])
  (1..5).each { |n| set.add(n) }
  expect(set).to eq(SetDataStructure.new([1,2,3,4,5]))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! :D

Comment: @pinglinh - you should upvote answers that you find helpful and also choose the best one. We get reputation points for every upvote and for every accepted answer.

Comment: Hi Marko, I believe I have already but it won't show since I don't have 15 reputation :(